# Use custom setter if class is inherited

Tags: inheritance, kotlin

I've got abstract class that contains abstract method and primary constructor

```
abstract class Article constructor(
    text: String
) {

    var text: String = text
        set(value) {
            assert(isValid(value))
            field = value
        }

    val isValid: Boolean = isValid(this.text)
    abstract fun isValid(text: String): Boolean
}
```

I also have another class that inherit/extends main.

```
class ShortArticle(
    text: String
) : Article(string) {
    override fun isValid(text: String) = text.length == 11 
}
```

I need to validate every article that is created and it also needs to inherit from Article abstract class.

But if I'm trying to create my child class like that:

```
ShortArticle("hello world blahlblahslab")
```

Validation (custom setter) is not invoked.
It's invoked in situation like that:

```
var article = ShortArticle("hello world blahlblahslab")
article.text = "new text that is validated"
```

I've tried to create function that is validating during assignment.

> var text: String = validation(text)

But its passing to ShortArticle *null* as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign it the way you do, it doesn't trigger the custom setter. It's similar to Java here, it just sets it directly and bypassing the setter. If you want to trigger the setter, you'd need to call it from the init block, or probably the constructor. However, since you're using a primary constructor only, I'll use the init block.

Due to an issue I don't understand myself, this is legal:

```
abstract class Article constructor(
    text: String
) {

    var text: String


    init { this.text = text }

    val isValid: Boolean = isValid(this.text)
    abstract fun isValid(text: String): Boolean
}
```

But this is not:

```
abstract class Article constructor(
    text: String
) {

    var text: String
        set(value) {
            assert(isValid(value))
            field = value
        }
    init { this.text = text }

    val isValid: Boolean = isValid(this.text)
    abstract fun isValid(text: String): Boolean

}
```

But you can partially get around this issue by declaring text like this:

```
var text: String = ""
    set(value) {
        assert(isValid(value))
        field = value
    }
```

Note that due to the order of initialization, the init block ***has*** to be after the initialization of the text variable, but before the initialization of the isValid variable. Otherwise, isValid goes off the `""` default value, and the field itself is false. However, I don't see any value for the field - you have the `isValid` function, which does act like a real-time updated version of the method. As in, if the order of the text field, isValid field, and init block is anything except this:

```
var text: String = ...
    set(value) { ... }
init { this.text = text; }

val isValid: Boolean = isValid(this.text)
```

It will fail. `text` after the init block will fail to compile, and `isValid` before the init block results in the `isValid` call using `""` instead of the real value of `text`

Speaking in terms of design, I'd go with something like this:

```
abstract class Article constructor(text: String) {

    var text: String = "" // required default value to enable initialization in the init block 
        set(value) {
            assert(isValid(value)) // checks the validity
            field = value
        }
    init { this.text = text } // assigns 

    protected abstract fun isValid(text: String): Boolean 

}
```

Due to the way you designed the class, it'll throw an exception if it isn't valid. Additionally, isValid is final, which means it won't change, rendering it pointless. I also made the `isValid` function is protected, because it's not a static function. It won't be usable for a validation unless the class is initialized, at which point it's too late to check anyway.

Comment: What are you recommending if my ShortArticle.isValid depends on _text_. Creating temp variable that will have it (f.g _text) that will be used to validation?

Comment: @MrNetroful Not entirely sure what you're asking, but assigning in the init block triggers the setter, which calls isValud with the assigned text. the text variable is still assigned, and the value is assigned. If you're looking to cache the results, I'd make a variable set from the isValid function (using a public variable with `private set(value) { field = value; }`). If you're asking about the variable, as long as the init block is before the initial assignment of the isValid boolean, it'll be assigned to the correct value, and using the real value of text, and not the placeholder

Comment: So that is "extra case" of this question. What if I'm going to place this in my ShortArticle: val strippedText; get() = super.text.trim() And would like to use strippedText in isValid method. Because currently firstly isValid will be invoked with "" instead of real text.

Comment: @MrNetroful you can use `val strippedText; get() { var c = super.text.trim(); assert(isValid(c)); return c; }` instead. (Clarifications: `c` here stands for `cache`, which is used to avoid calling trim several times. the getter can contain complex operations, just like the setter. `isValid()` is still accessible. There's also no strip method in Java or Kotlin - use `trim` instead)

Comment: In this case its fine but what if I need to generate.
list of words f.g `val wordList = super.text.split()`. I mean that when it will be firstly called then default value will be passed which is "" instead of my _text_ passed to constructor etc. Thats because its currently stored in super class.

Comment: @MrNetroful if you do that in a child class, `text` will be properly initialized. The super class is initialized before the child class, Further, you still have the same text variable passed to the primary constructor of the child class

Comment: Yes but during creating  child.isValid _text_ parameter is not initialized(validated) yet and its value is default(""). But I need it in my Child's class isValid method. I've made vorkaround by adding another property like __text_ which is initialized without validation and using this variable during Child's isValid process.

Comment: Update to my previous comment: `val strippedText` needs to be declared as `val strippedText
        get() = super.text.trim().also { assert(isValid(it)); }`. Using a full body getter seems to break it.

Answer (score 2):

You can add explicit set value to `Article` constructor. Then validation will be invoked

```
abstract class Article constructor(
    text: String
) {
    var text: String = ""
        set(value) {
            assert(isValid(value))
            field = value
        }

    init {
        this.text = text
    }

    val isValid: Boolean = isValid(this.text)
    abstract fun isValid(text: String): Boolean
}
```